# classList.add() Insert variable instead of string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a loop that changes the class of an element everytime it is executed. The problem is that

```
classList.add('something')
```

requires string and I need to put a variable there, here is my code:

```
const head = document.createElement('div');

function change_head() {
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < head_class.length; i += 1){
        diffrent_head = head_class[i];
        head.classList.add(head_class[i]);
    }
};
```

Hope it is possible to somehow use a variable here.

Answer (score 2):

In your `head_class` array, you have objects with a field `name`, which has a string value. Use that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < head_class.length; i += 1){
    head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to access the `.name` property in order to get to the string:

```
head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
```

```js
const head = document.createElement('div');

function change_head() {
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < head_class.length; i += 1){
        diffrent_head = head_class[i];
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
    }
}
change_head();
console.log(head.className);
```

But there's a better looking option - you can `.map` the `head_class` to just the strings (extract the `.name` property from each), then spread the array of strings into `.add`, resulting in `.add` being called only *once*:

```js
const head = document.createElement('div');

function change_head() {
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    head.classList.add(
      ...head_class.map(({ name }) => name)
    );
}
change_head();
console.log(head.className);
```